# Passing Alexa a command from a skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

We have a client with an oddball question and couldn't find any precedence. Is it possible for a custom Alexa skill to pass a command to Alexa?

For example, something like this:

> Alexa, ask Test let's chat

The skill would then pass to Alexa:

> Alexa, let's chat

Something like that? My gut says no but wanted to farm it to the internet as y'all tend to be a bit more knowledgeable than I :P

Any links to sources would be much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "The skill would then pass to Alexa:", Is it like we give a command to a skill and then the skill should in turn ask it to Alexa itself??

Comment: Yes, I believe that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly the way how *intents* in Alexa custom skills work.

In your case you would create a custom skill called `Test`. Then you would create a intent, which would be your "command". You then can define some sample utterances like
`let's chat` or `let's start a chat`.

This utterances would trigger the intent, which then can perform any desired action on a service API.

From the Alexa Skills Kit docs (https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/create-intents-utterances-and-slots.html):

> An intent represents an action that fulfills a user's spoken request. Intents can optionally have arguments called slots. The sample utterances are set of likely spoken phrases mapped to the intents.

Comment: Just to verify, you could write a skill where `Alexa, ask Test {{command}}` always returns the same result as `Alexa, {{command}}`?

Comment: You always need to mention the skill name `Test` in the sentence. Otherwise you need to start the skill first `Start test` and then you can just say `{{command}}`. You can find the docs for starting custom skills here: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/understanding-how-users-invoke-custom-skills.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you cannot create a Skill that interacts with the Alexa itself. For example, if I say "Alexa, ask Test let's chat", it wouldn't able to pass that information to Alexa since a Skill will interact with the service or API you build behind it.

So turning "Alexa, ask Test let's chat" into a command for Alexa as "Alexa, let's chat" isn't possible. Effectively, Skills are sandboxed from the Alexa device.

Comment: Thanks Niraj, that was my thinking as well.